# Why trust-region-reflective algorithm in fmincon require a gradient as input?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, newtons-method

According to Matlab fmincon [documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-nonlcon), the 'trust-region-reflective' algorithm needs to specify the objective gradient. I read the algorithm [explanation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html#brnpd5f) but yet, I cannot understand the reason for that.
1- Why does it need gradient as input?
2- Does the objective function have to be analytical? since my objective function, is function handle that calculates some matrix as output
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The objective should return a scalar, not a matrix. A matrix would bring you to the more exotic field of multi-objective optimization.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, assuming that I calculate the average of matrix and have a scalar as output.
Would you please let me know that:
 1- Why does it need gradient as input?
 2- Does the objective function have to be analytical? 
Thanks

Comment: There are algorithms that don't require gradients (DFO), ones that require first derivatives and others that need both first and second derivatives.  Gradient-based solvers can show better convergence. You mean analytic? That is more a concept from Analysis. I don't think that is used as a requirement for numerical algorithms. The usual assumptions include continuity, differentiability and smoothnes.

Comment: @S.M please update your question with your response to Erwin Kalvelagen.  Comments can be deleted and any important details should be captured in the question text

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your reply. As I described in the question and provided the documentation link, Matlab ask for gradient as input for the "trus-regionb-reflective' algorithms. Where, for other algorithms such as 'SQP", it does not need the gradient as INPUT. My question was why it ask gradient as INPUT? Since to my understanding, you can calculate the gradient of a function, if you have the formula for the objective function, otherwise you need to approximate it numerically. Whereas, other derivative based algorithm does not need gradient as INPUT in MATLAB